# How to fix "SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: {table_name}.{singular_table_name}_id:"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm creating a Ruby on Rails web application, and want to be able to delete records from the `countries` table. When I attempt to delete any records from the `countries` table from any where in my application, I get an error that says:

> SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: countries.country_id: SELECT >"countries".* FROM "countries" WHERE "countries"."country_id" = ?

I am not sure why this is happening.

I am using ActiveAdmin. I have 2 other tables in the application: `cities` and `sites`. There is an association between the models that I included in my routing:

```
resources :countries do
    resources :cities do
      resources :sites
    end
  end
  resources :countries
  resources :cities
  resources :sites
```

Where `City` model belongs to `Country` and `Country` has many `cities` and where `Site` belongs to `City` and `City` has many `sites`.

Comment: The error message tells you exactly why this is happening `no such column: countries.country_id`

Comment: You are right, but I didn't define it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the solution to my issue. In the `Country` model, I had a typo that said

```
class Country < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :countries, dependent: :destroy
    validates :code, presence: true, uniqueness: true
end
```

Which is why I was getting the Sqlite3 exception error; because the database assumed I should have a `country_id` since `country` has many `countries`, I think. Anyways, I changed `countries` above to `cities`, and it worked like a charm. Thanks for the help, SOS.